# Vyper convert address to String

Tags: vyper

How do I convert a variable of type `address` to a `string[n]` in Vyper?

For example, to achieve a function where only part of the address is displayed as 0xABCD...ABCD instead of the entire address.

Here is what I tried (but doesn't compile):

```
# @version ^0.2.16

publicOwner: public(String[12])

@external
def __init__():
    _address_str: String[40] = convert(msg.sender, String[40])
    self.publicOwner = concat(slice(_address_str, 0, 4), "....", "slice(_address_str, 36, 4))
```

Also tried converting `address` -> `bytes32` -> `string[]`, which compiles but the output is not as expected:

```
# @version ^0.2.16

publicOwner: public(String[5])

@external
def __init__():
    _address_bytes32: bytes32 = convert(msg.sender, bytes32)
    self.publicOwner = convert(slice(_address_bytes32, 0, 5), String[5])
```

The output here is something like [unprintable] or `x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`

Comment: Can you add more details about your question?

Comment: I have an 'address' which is a data type in Vyper. I want to convert it to string[x] which is another data type. How?